# npm: Installed git repo fails as package

Tags: node.js, npm

I forked and modified a git repo, then tried to install it with `npm i {repo name}` At first I thought it installed correctly.

```
// package.json
  "react-big-calendar": "git+https://github.com/seanprpl/fkCalendar.git",
```

But referencing this fork during import throws an exception during compile.

```
./pages/admin/calendar/index.js:5:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-big-calendar'
  3 | import Header from '../../../modules/Header/Header';
  4 | import { Container } from '../../../layouts/components';
> 5 | import { Calendar as RBCalendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
  6 | import moment from "moment";
  7 | 
  8 | const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
```

Does anyone know why this result may happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Although you have used Git to download the project, the problem has nothing to do with Git. See [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67813662/1256452) regarding the need to run build first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project has [build steps](https://github.com/seanprpl/fkCalendar/blob/master/package.json#L51) that would be run before a publish to npm.

If you want to source the package from git, all the build output will need to be added to the repo.

It looks like the `lib/` and `dist/` [directories that are gitignored](https://github.com/seanprpl/fkCalendar/blob/master/.gitignore#L1-L2) are the [main entry points](https://github.com/seanprpl/fkCalendar/blob/master/package.json#L14-L16).